# can anyone explain to me this piece of code in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter,can your explain this ligns of code in flutter.

```
              children: [
                Question(_questions.elementAt(_questionIndex)['questionText']),
                ...(_questions.elementAt(_questionIndex)['answers']as List<String>).map((answer) {
                 return Answer(answerQuestion, answer);
                }).toList(),
```

Answer is dart file which returns a container (elevated button to be specific).BTW this is the
Defintion of some terms used in this code:

```
int _questionIndex = 0;
  List _questions = [
    {
      'questionText': 'What is your favorite animal ?',
      'answers': ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish'],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What is your favorite color ?',
      'answers': ['Blue', 'Red', 'Yellow', 'Green'],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What is your favorite character ?',
      'answers': ['A', 'B'],
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Are questions about coding not allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is supposed to create a List of Widgets corresponding to the number of items in the _question list.

But there is a better way to do this; by using **`map`**:

```
chidden: _questions.map((element){
   Question(element. questionText, element.answers), //If Question() is a Widget
}).toList(),
```

Then in your Question Widget:

```
class Question extends StatelessWidget{
   final String question;
   final List<String> answers;

   Question(this.question, this.answers);

   @override
   _QuestionState createState() => _QuestionState();
}

class _QuestionState extends State<Question>{
   
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context){
      return Container(
         child: Column(
           children: [ 
            Text(question),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            Column(
              children: widget.answers.map((answer){
                  return ElevatedButton(
                     child: Text(answer),
                     onPressed:(){
                        //Do something when an answer is selected
                     }
                  );
               }).toList()),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
         ),
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: yes sir ,now i understand that ,thank u so much for ur explanation :)